# Why don't regexec(), regcomp(), followed by print statements execute immediately?

Tags: c, regex, printf, posix, flush

I have a functioning HTTP server coded in C. In my quest to add regex functionality to it I've encountered strange functionality of my program.
My main function looks like this:

```
int main(void)

{
    char *example = "index.html";
    regex_t REGEXhtml;
    int mond = 1;
    if(regcomp(&REGEXhtml, ".html", 0)){printf("REGEX error 1"); return -1;}
    mond = regexec(&REGEXhtml, example, 0, NULL, 0);
    if(!mond) {printf("FOUND HTML");}
    printf("%i", mond);

    //......server code ........
}
```

For some reason, when executing this code after compilation the print statements will **NEVER** be printed and my program will seemingly idle infinitely. This is expected behavior without the above code, since my server will idle in the terminal and wait for a connection, then log it to the terminal.
Unexpectedly, the program isn't just hanging there. When someone connects to my server, the printf statements are printed as they should, followed by my server logging printf statements.

As this goes against my current understanding of programming, I researched this problem a little bit and found the following from the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html#:%7E:text=For%20an%20explanation%20of%20the%20terms%20used%20in%20this%20section%2C%20see%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20attributes(7).):

> │regcomp(), regexec()           │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe locale

and the attributes link describes this as meaning:

> ```
>    locale Functions annotated with locale as an MT-Safety issue read
>           from the locale object without any form of
>           synchronization.  Functions annotated with locale called
>           concurrently with locale changes may behave in ways that
>           do not correspond to any of the locales active during
>           their execution, but an unpredictable mix thereof.
> ```

Does that accurately explain the above behavior? I'm rather confused how having these functions can seemingly delay the execution of my print statements, especially the last one.
And if that description is related, what are the technicalities of what exactly is happening here, both during execution and compilation?

**Edit:**    So DannyNiu below fixed my simple mistake, but I'm still interested in an example of the MT-Safety locale and its implications on other parts of code. If anyone has examples or links to explanations please post/comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` (thus `printf`) is fully buffered unless `libc` detects it's outputting to a terminal window, in which case it's line-buffered.

Try adding newline characters to the end of the output string, or adding `fflush` calls.

Comment: Wow! With an answer like that I'm almost embarrased. I somehow had no idea that was the way printf() functioned, this seems to be the simple answer to my problem

Comment: It's okay, I was surprised with the way it's defined in POSIX at first as well.

Comment: (a) Buffering is a property of the stream, not `printf`, per C 2018 7.21.3 3. E.g., it happens even if `putchar` and `fwrite` are used, not just `printf`. (b) The rule in the C standard is that standard input and standard output are fully buffered by default (it can be changed in the program) if and only if the stream cannot be determined not to refer to an interactive device. (This differs from the statement in the answer in that it allows the streams to be unbuffered and in the behavior when the detection is inconclusive.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just noticed the mistake (a), and amended accordingly. I'm not sure how to fix for (b), hope you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit**: So DannyNiu below fixed my simple mistake, but I'm still interested in an example of the MT-Safety locale and its implications on other parts of code. If anyone has examples or links to explanations please post/comment below

Locale is designed for internationalization and localization of textual input and output of programs.

A process has a global locale associated with it, this local should usually be set by main thread. For a multi-threaded program, it's usually unnecessary to change the locale within a subsidiary thread (non-main thread) since most of the time, the program interats with a user in one language only.

But there are exceptions, such as when loading a file encoded in another locale. In this case, locale objects see their use.

For example, the case insensitive string comparison functions `strcasecmp(3)` and `strcasecmp_l(3)` are locale-dependent, but `strcasecmp_l(3)` can take an locale object (avoid dependency on global states), which allow it to do text processing in a different locale than the main thread.